# javascript pizza menu select list

Tags: javascript

i just start to study Javascript.i try to do a pizza menu for my class and i got a trouble there, i need to make a select list and put pizza size choices in there, so i did:

```
<form name="pizzasize">
    <select name="pizzafirst" id="pizzafirst" onchange="findsize()">
        <option value="10" id="small">Small</option>
        <option value="12" id="medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="15" id="large">Large</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and when i click the size, i will have different price add to the total, small is $10, medium is $12; and the large is $15. so i did the code below:

```
var pizzafirst ;
function findsize(){
pizza1 = document.pizzasize.pizzafirst.selectedIndex;

if (pizzafirst == 0 ){
    document.getElementById('pform').innerHTML == + 10;
}
if (pizzafirst == 1 ){
    document.getElementById('pform').innerHTML == + 12;
}

if (pizzafirst == 2){
    document.getElementById('pform').innerHTML == + 15;
}
document.getElementById('pform').innerHTML = 0
}
```

Comment: `==` checks comparison and unary + casts to Number.  There is no need to cast things like `12` to number (they're already number), and you're looking for `=`. Moreover you can write this more elegantly by calculating the sum outside of the its and then assigning it once as  `document.getElementById('pform').innerHTML = [10,12,15][pizzaFirst]||0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are better ways to do this, since you do have values in the options already:

```
var pizza_select = document.getElementById('pizzafirst');
var result = document.getElementById('pform');

pizza_select.onchange = function () {
    result.innerHTML = '$' + this.value;
};
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G46B2/1/)**

**EDIT:**

You can add a extra 
`<option value="" id="select">Select a size...</option>`.
I added that on the demo also.

Comment: +1 Nice and clean, especially liked the comment that there are better ways to do this - it would be even better if you elaborate on that.

Comment: awesome answer, but wouldn't it be `$ + this.value`?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea, I am european... should the `$` be before the number?

Comment: haha sorry i was literally just thinking "he probably is european" ... yeah, for USD its $ first, value second.

Comment: just a heads up, the jsFiddle didn't work, likely because there was no event listener. I updated the jsFiddle to use either `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`, depending on browser support. works now => http://jsfiddle.net/yauJC/2/

Comment: @PlantTheIdea, thanks. Had used  `  instead of  '  - does this work in your browser http://jsfiddle.net/yauJC/3/

Comment: yup, all good. and here i went through the effort of refining mine to include a 'select a size' option => http://jsfiddle.net/yauJC/5/ ... damn my obsessive tendencies ...

Comment: @PlantTheIdea, the extra `<option>` is a good idea! Added that to the answer.